# how find time-difference based on another column

Tags: python

I have a dataset like this

```
user-id      date-time                   msg
  1          2016-12-09 10:25:00          1
  2          2016-12-09 10:26:00          0
  3          2016-12-09 10:26:00          1
  2          2016-12-09 10:27:00          1
  1          2016-12-09 10:28:00          2
  2          2016-12-09 10:28:00          1
  3          2016-12-09 10:29:00          2
  2          2016-12-09 10:29:00          1
  1          2016-12-09 10:30:00          3
```

I want to have a new column that calculates the time difference between each record and the first time that the message is similar to that record. Something like this :

```
 user-id      date-time                  msg        time-diffrence
  1          2016-12-09 10:25:00          1            00:00
  2          2016-12-09 10:26:00          0            00:00
  3          2016-12-09 10:26:00          1            01:00
  2          2016-12-09 10:27:00          1            02:00
  1          2016-12-09 10:28:00          2            00:00
  2          2016-12-09 10:28:00          1            03:00
  3          2016-12-09 10:29:00          2            01:00
  2          2016-12-09 10:29:00          1            04:00
  1          2016-12-09 10:30:00          3            00:00
```

I found the solution that only considers date-time, or using loc or iloc, but they did not work for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Option #1

Use `groupby` and `iloc`:

```
df['time-difference'] = df.groupby('msg')['date-time'].apply(lambda x: x - x.iloc[0])
```

Output:

```
   user-id           date-time  msg time-difference
0        1 2016-12-09 10:25:00    1        00:00:00
1        2 2016-12-09 10:26:00    0        00:00:00
2        3 2016-12-09 10:26:00    1        00:01:00
3        2 2016-12-09 10:27:00    1        00:02:00
4        1 2016-12-09 10:28:00    2        00:00:00
5        2 2016-12-09 10:28:00    1        00:03:00
6        3 2016-12-09 10:29:00    2        00:01:00
7        2 2016-12-09 10:29:00    1        00:04:00
8        1 2016-12-09 10:30:00    3        00:00:00
```

### Option #2

Use `groupby` with `transform` and `first` or `min`:

```
df['time-difference'] = df['date-time'] - df.groupby('msg')['date-time'].transform('first')
```

Output:

```
   user-id           date-time  msg time-difference
0        1 2016-12-09 10:25:00    1        00:00:00
1        2 2016-12-09 10:26:00    0        00:00:00
2        3 2016-12-09 10:26:00    1        00:01:00
3        2 2016-12-09 10:27:00    1        00:02:00
4        1 2016-12-09 10:28:00    2        00:00:00
5        2 2016-12-09 10:28:00    1        00:03:00
6        3 2016-12-09 10:29:00    2        00:01:00
7        2 2016-12-09 10:29:00    1        00:04:00
8        1 2016-12-09 10:30:00    3        00:00:00
```